# How do I click a button on Safari mobile with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ios, safari

I am trying to make a Siri Shortcut to click a "play" button on this website: https://newonce.net/radio

I know I can use JavaScript in Safari, but how do I make it click a specific button? I can't seem to find the button's id using "inspect" option.

I have tried this:

```
document.getElementById('button').click();
```

To try and click the first button which occurs, but I got error "null is not an object"

What else can I try?

Answer (score 0):

okay, I managed to do it like this:

```
const playButton = document.querySelectorAll('.IconButton_iconButton__3wFY4.IconButton_primary__1mImd.IconButton_big__39d5I.Radio_playButton__35cjK');
playButton.forEach(btn => btn.click());
```